# SQL Where 2 values one is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, record

I'm struggling whit some SQL code for some hours now. I'm trying to combine 2 different values in one row, but if one value is not there (so no result) there will not row at all.

To be more clear: I have a Location whit 2 different values, those are coming from two queries. That is working fine, but sometime the second query give no results (can happen, is not bad), but than also the first value is not shown.

```
Declare @Start datetime,
        @Ende datetime; 
SET @Start = '01.04.2015';
SET @Ende = '30.04.2015';

SELECT t1.[Location Code], CAST(t1.Umsatz as DECIMAL(18,2))as Umsatz , CAST(t2.Ersatznachweis as DECIMAL(18,2)) as Ersatznachweis
FROM (
SELECT [Location Code],  SUM(WareBrutto) AS Umsatz

FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT [Location Code], [Document No_] , WareBrutto from [Item Ledger Entry] 
      WHERE [Location Code] > '0000' and [Location Code] < '0040' and [Document Date] >= @Start and [Document Date] <= @Ende) t
GROUP BY [Location Code]) as t1,

(select [Location Code], sum([Quantity]*Bruttopreis) as Ersatznachweis  from [Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Location Code] > '0000' and [Location Code] < '0040' and [Item No_] not IN ('00009000','00009900','00009906') and Gutschrift = '1' and [Document Date] >= @Start and [Document Date] <= @Ende
Group By [Location Code]) as t2

where t1.[Location Code] = t2.[Location Code]
order by t1.[Location Code]
```

It is the second query that sometimes does not return a value.

```
 (select [Location Code], sum([Quantity]*Bruttopreis) as Ersatznachweis  from [Item Ledger Entry] 
    where [Location Code] > '0000' and [Location Code] < '0040' and [Item No_] not IN ('00009000','00009900','00009906') and Gutschrift = '1' and [Document Date] >= @Start and [Document Date] <= @Ende
    Group By [Location Code]) as t2
```

But that when it comes to the end and there is no result of t2.[Location code] the result of t1 is also not shown.

```
where t1.[Location Code] = t2.[Location Code]
```

I want that t2 gets a value of zero when there is no result. I tried isnull and the coalesec option but I was not able to get a decent result. It is just not there or I get error messages.

Thank in advanced...

Using Toad for SQl on a 2012 MSSQL server.

Comment: Remove the commas from your `from` clause and use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  You'll probably then be able to easily spot and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the comma join and where clause you're using makes the join an inner join (Thanks to the comment from [Ed B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310971/ed-b) for adding details to this). In an inner join, only matching records are shown. Since there are no records in t2, nothing is matching in t1, and no records are returned. You're looking for a LEFT join, which will join any matching records from the 2nd table to the returned records from the 1st table. If nothing is in the 2nd table, you still get all of the original records from the 1st table.

I've updated your code so it uses a LEFT join, does the join in an ON statement instead of a where, and uses COALESCE to show 0 instead of NULL for records that don't match.

The following should get what you're looking for:

```
Declare @Start datetime,
        @Ende datetime; 
SET @Start = '01.04.2015';
SET @Ende = '30.04.2015';

SELECT t1.[Location Code], CAST(t1.Umsatz as DECIMAL(18,2))as Umsatz , CAST(COALESCE(t2.Ersatznachweis, 0) as DECIMAL(18,2)) as Ersatznachweis
FROM (
SELECT [Location Code],  SUM(WareBrutto) AS Umsatz

FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT [Location Code], [Document No_] , WareBrutto from [Item Ledger Entry] 
      WHERE [Location Code] > '0000' and [Location Code] < '0040' and [Document Date] >= @Start and [Document Date] <= @Ende) t
GROUP BY [Location Code]) as t1

LEFT JOIN (select [Location Code], sum([Quantity]*Bruttopreis) as Ersatznachweis  from [Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Location Code] > '0000' and [Location Code] < '0040' and [Item No_] not IN ('00009000','00009900','00009906') and Gutschrift = '1' and [Document Date] >= @Start and [Document Date] <= @Ende
Group By [Location Code]) as t2 ON t1.[Location Code] = t2.[Location Code]
order by t1.[Location Code]
```

Comment: The OP should be aware that the 'comma join' is actually a `CARTESIAN JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN`, where every record from one side of the comma is correlated with every record on the other side. In this case, it is only the `WHERE` clause that makes it effectively an `INNER JOIN`. It is good practice to avoid this `JOIN` syntax unless you really DO want a cartesian product, and to use the `{[INNER] | {LEFT | RIGHT} [OUTER]} JOIN <table> ON <condition>` syntax instead, which has the added advantage of improving readability by keeping your join and filter conditions separate.

Comment: Thanks, than one worked. Now i will try to add a 3rd query to it. Will that work on the same way?

Comment: Depending on the join statement used. If you do a left join onto the first table (t1.col = t3.col), then matching records from the 3rd table will be shown. If you do the join onto the 2nd table (t2.col = t3.col), it will show matching records from the 3rd table only when the 2nd table is matching the first table. In the first example, t1.col = t3.col, this is a new join even though it's part of the same query, which it sounds like might be what you're looking for. Here is a link on joins that might help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use a better syntax in your statements. Use a join instead of select from 2 comma seperated tables.
Then you'll see that you'll need a left join.

```
SELECT ... AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ...) AS t2 ON t1.[Location Code] = t2.[Location Code]
...
```